# Add "Vote Up" button for external sites similar to Facebook's "Like" button.

Tags: feature-request, support, api, social-networking

I would like being able to post in my blog an exact copy an SO answer.

I have already an script that can extract a question and my answer by parsing the page. However I would like to go one step further:

Having a "vote me up" kind of button, just like those "Tweet" "Like" buttons. It should not matter if you are reading me in my own blog or SO, users should be able to up-vote my answers from my own blog. This would make SO behave more like other social networks (G+, Twitter, Facebook...). It seems easy to implement, just missing the right button and javascript code for it.

Is this already supported by the current APIs? Is there an official icon / code for it?

**small side question regarding this topic:**

Do you know of any script using the SO API to mirror a SO answer in both directions? I have my posts on Github as markdown files. It would be really amazing to link SO and my blog to the same source, but I guess that is another story...

Comment: You always remain the owner of your content, you just license it to SO under the Creative Commons license. You don't seriously think SO employees downvoted this suggestion for political reasons, do you?

Comment: nah, I am already used to being downvoted in meta. I forget meta is different to all other SO stacks because meta works more like a voting place "bad/good proposal" instead of "good/bad question". To me any downvote feels useless if people dont explain why. I voted up your answer and I hope you downvoted me! :-)    However I do feel SO sites are slowly disconnecting from some current social-engineering trends (read as one term, not two), despite starting a whole new trend itself. I do not believe there is any evil in SO sites at all, but some times feel I do not get some political interests.

Comment: Francisco - I don't think they are opposed to using social networks where it fits (see the share buttons on some posts, etc.) I'm not fundamentally opposed to having more ways to embed your SO content into your own blogs etc... but as said below, I think this specific way wouldn't work

Comment: @Pekka I am used to ask in the other stack sites. I do believe my question is good, but while elsewhere a down vote means "your question sucks", in meta is more likely to mean "no, not a good idea". Because of this, I believe some/other people might get a bad rap of the meta site. Once time more again, I love SO stack websites, great job, no evilness expected from you guys... except next comments saying... "yes, your question do suck"

Comment: Yeah, I agree the voting system here is imperfect.

Comment: "_This would make SO behave more like other social networks_" - that would be a Bad Thing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To me, an embeddable Stack Overflow "vote" widget would make no sense at all.  Facebook's or Google Plus's "Like" functionalities are fundamentally different from voting on Stack Overflow, they serve completely different purposes.

- An external voting widget would defeat the core purpose of SO's voting system: Voting is used for *competition* between multiple contributions, to distinguish good from bad content. In your model, the voting user would have no way to compare your answer with other answers given. They would see only your contribution; they could not comment on it, nor see what has changed since you scraped the page.
- important comments might have been added to the Stack Overflow page since you scraped the page.
- A remote "vote answer up" button also would have to ensure that your scraped version is always 100% identical to the version on SO, which can be subject to editing by you or others. That would be insanely complicated, if not impossible, to do technically.

Nobody is keeping you from publishing your content on your own blog -  if the help you give to fellow SO users can benefit you by enriching your blog as well, that's great. (Just note that the *question* you answer is licensed to you under the CC license, and you need to follow [attribution guidelines](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) for that part.)  But I don't see how tying that content to Stack Overflow's voting system could work in a sane way.